# X11 appears to be stuck on DISPLAY (:1) affecting nvim yank

Tags: 22.04, xorg, xfce, environment-variables

**My Problem**

Today I discovered that my "native" display is `:1` as seen below:

```
$ who
kwilkins :1           2023-11-27 22:13 (:1)
```

This is affecting the ability to yank in nvim.  My only hope is to issue `DISPLAY=":1" nvim` and I can yank, **but** there is no confirmation of how many lines are yanked.

**Troubleshooting I have done:**

1. Rebooted computer
2. Updated and upgraded packages
3. Issued `systemctl restart display-manager` to see if that forces X11 back to using `:0`
4. Have checked the `/tmp/.X11-unix` directory and can only see the following:

```
/tmp/.X11-unix$ ll
total 24
drwxrwxrwt  2 root     root      4096 Nov 27 22:13 ./
drwxrwxrwt 27 root     root     20480 Nov 27 22:27 ../
srwxrwxrwx  1 kwilkins kwilkins     0 Nov 27 22:13 X1=
```

The `X1=` file seems to be concerning to me.  So far no Google search has landed me on anything that can tell me how to force X11 to use `:0` instead of `:1` which it is using now.

5. I have issued a `export DISPLAY=":0"` and when sending the `who` command I still see

```
kwilkins :1           2023-11-27 22:13 (:1)
```

6. As a sanity check I issued `xhost +si:localuser:root` to enable (and then disable) access control and I get the error: `xhost: unable to open display ":0"`.

**My hypothesis and assumption**

X11 is stuck on display :1 and seems unable to switch to :0.

**What I want to know**

1. Is there a solution or fix around this?
2. Is the `X1=` file under `/tmp/.X11-unix` something I can remove then restart system without any adverse effects?
3. Is there anything else I should check that I have not thought of searching?